# Site timeout for Android device on LAN, but ok on mobile network

Tags: wi-fi, networking

My two Android devices (LG G3 on KitKat; Nexus 7 with custom JB rom) cannot access 4 of my 5 Wordpress sites over my WLAN, but have no problem via my mobile network. The other devices on the WLAN (iPhone, Mac, PC) access the sites successfully. The problem has existed for a long time (years), and I am finally trying to solve it.

To test, I just created a completely new Wordpress installation, with no plugins active. The same problem is observed. http://testing.dunques.id.au

The successful request via *mobile network* shows this in the server logs:

```
49.183.x.x - - [30/Apr/2016:01:24:28 -0400] \
"GET /instructions/making-a-test-recording/ HTTP/1.1" 200 61814 "-" \
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; LG-x Build/KOT49I.x) \
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.103 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

The logs show *no entries* for the timed-out request from the Android devices *via WLAN*, made immediately beforehand. I assume that means there is a problem between the devices and the router (FritzBox 7390), or something happening when the request reaches the host server (Namecheap). All sites (including the one that is always accessible) are on the same server.

There are no white/blacklist entries in the router.

I've not been able to identify other Wordpress sites that have the same problem, but there have historically been a few sites which have timed out... though causes may have been unrelated.

Posting this question because I don't know what more to do to diagnose this.

UPDATE:
Using FritzBox logging, the traffic to the site looks like this. Currently, the sites are sometimes accessible, but often with a long delay (perhaps the precursor to the timeout I observed frequently previously).

```
//start of request//
22:25.8 118.209.x.x 199.188.x.x TCP 92  52268  >  80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1263984 TSecr=0 WS=64
22:25.8 118.209.x.x 199.188.x.x TCP 92  52269  >  80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1263984 TSecr=0 WS=64
22:25.8 118.209.x.x 199.188.x.x TCP 92  52270  >  80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1263984 TSecr=0 WS=64
22:26.0 118.209.x.x 199.188.x.x TCP 92  52271  >  80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1264008 TSecr=0 WS=64

22:26.8 118.209.x.x 199.188.x.x TCP 92  [TCP Retransmission] 52268  >  80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1264084 TSecr=0 WS=64
// 18 requests like this in 31 seconds //**

22:57.1 199.188.x.x 118.209.x.x TCP 92  80  >  52268 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14480 Len=0 MSS=1420 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2355200105 TSecr=1267092 WS=512
22:57.1 199.188.x.x 118.209.x.x TCP 92  80  >  52269 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14480 Len=0 MSS=1420 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2355200106 TSecr=1267092 WS=512
22:57.1 199.188.x.x 118.209.x.x TCP 92  80  >  52270 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14480 Len=0 MSS=1420 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2355200108 TSecr=1267092 WS=512
22:57.1 118.209.40.221  199.188.x.x TCP 92  [TCP Retransmission] 52271  >  80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1267116 TSecr=0 WS=64
22:57.1 118.209.40.221  199.188.x.x TCP 84  52268  >  80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=14656 Len=0 TSval=1267117 TSecr=2355200105
22:57.1 118.209.40.221  199.188.x.x HTTP    552 GET / HTTP/1.1 
// remaining requests seem OK, site rendered //
```

Comment: Can you access the same sites from a computer using the same network your Android device uses? First thing coming to my mind here is a firewall/iptables rule on the server side blocking your IP (range).

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, all devices including the iPhone, Mac and PC are on the same WLAN.

Comment: Thanks – must have missed that. OK, next thing to check would be the logs on your router (I think of some kind of "child protection"/blacklisting which might be in place there), plus logs from the device itself (see our [logging tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) for help on that).

Comment: Updated the question with router log data.